# Unhandled rejection SequelizeHostNotFoundError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND in sequelize

Tags: node.js, phpmyadmin, sequelize.js

trying to connect sequelize to remote phpmyadmin server.

```
"development": {
   "username": "MyUserName",
   "password": "MyPassword",
   "database": "MeetUpDB",
   "host": "http://ipAddress/phpmyadmin/",
   "dialect": "mysql",
   "operatorsAliases": 0
 },
```

but getting this error

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeHostNotFoundError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://ipAddress/phpmyadmin/
    at C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\meetup backend\meetup_bknd\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:127:19
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\meetup backend\meetup_bknd\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\meetup backend\meetup_bknd\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\meetup backend\meetup_bknd\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\meetup backend\meetup_bknd\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\meetup backend\meetup_bknd\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\meetup backend\meetup_bknd\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\meetup backend\meetup_bknd\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\meetup backend\meetup_bknd\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\meetup backend\meetup_bknd\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

how to connect to remote phpMyAdmin from sequelize.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect to a DBMS administration tool and not to a DBMS itself. Indicate IP/hostname of a DBMS in the 'host' option.